# Updating MySQL row headers from dictionary key (Python)

Tags: python, mysql, variables, dictionary

I've compiled the below script in Python 2.x which to recursively search a directory and for each JPEG found, parse out the metadata and place it into a dictionary. At present, the output is simply printed to console:-

```
import os
import fnmatch
import pyexiv2

matches = []
dict1 = {}

# The aim of this script is to recursively search across a directory for all
# JPEG files. Each time a JPEG image is detected, the script used the PYEXIV2
# module to extract all EXIF, IPTC and XMP data from the image. Once extracted
# the key (ie. "camera make" is generated and it's respective value
# (ie. Canon) is then added as the value in a dictionary.

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('C:\Users\XXX\Desktop'):
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.jpg'):
      matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

for entry in matches:
    metadata = pyexiv2.ImageMetadata(entry)
    metadata.read()
    keys = metadata.exif_keys + metadata.iptc_keys + metadata.xmp_keys
    for key in keys:
        dict1[key] = metadata[key].raw_value

    print entry
    print str(dict1)
```

What I am looking to do is output the results to a MySQL DB. Now, my problem is that I don't have an indefinite list of the metadata headers and indeed I have struggled to locate one and so, for my table row headers, I am looking to compare each value in the dictionary key (ie. date taken, make, model etc...) and if it doesn't exist in the table, for it to be added to my table as a header and for the EXIF data (the key value) to then be entered into the respective columns. I've had a play with MySQL through Python previously but never to compare row headers and dynamically create new ones from variables.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: why you need to put it in MySQL DB when your columns are dynamic?

Comment: @AnuragUniyal, I want to run some comparisons for commonality (ie. query all photos with the serial number ABCDE for example)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding new data keys as new columns in MySQL table, create a fixed single table with three columns `file`, `data_name`, `data_value` and then you can have dynamic data per file.

You can then easily query the table e.g.

```
select file from file_data where data_name = 'Serial' and data_value = 'ABCDE'
```

For multiple field matching you can do a self join e.g.

```
SELECT * from data t1 JOIN data t2 on t1.file_name = t2.file_name and t1.data_name = "data1" and t1.data_value="value1" and t2.data_name = "data2" and t2.data_value="value2"
```

**Alternatively** you can just keep on appending columns to MySQL table dynamically e.g

```
ALTER TABLE data ADD Serial VARCHAR(60);
```

You can get the existing columns name using

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `data`;
```

So every-time you see a new data field add it as column.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will be looking to query more than one commonality though so I may look to query all images with a serial number of ABCDE and a model of "Canon" for example.

Comment: @thefragileomen For multiple field matching you can do a self join